# How to find eigenvalues of the following block circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

I have a block matrix of size PN x PN of the form:

[image]

Where A and C are P x P matrices. I would like to find the eigenvalues of the matrix B, that is

[image]

where

[image]

Comment: Did that answer your question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress can be made if $A,C$ are commuting diagonalizable matrices, then one knows that they have a common set of eigenvectors. Call them $v_i$. Then note that the matrix $M$ can be written as a polynomial in the circulant matrix where the top row is $(0,0,...,0,1)$ and each row down you cyclically permute the entries of this vector to the right.

This is an orthogonal matrix whose eigenvectors and eigenvalues are not too difficult to compute. Call this circulant matrix $T$ then the matrix $M$ is equal to $T^{n-1}+T^{n-2}+...+T$. Inserting the eigenvectors of $T$ tensored with the common eigenvectors of $A$ and $C$ you get the eigenvalues of your matrix $B$.

Unfortunately, I do not see anything one could do in the general case.

Comment: The first line I wrote I realized was wrong, I edited accordingly..

Answer (score 2):

$$\det(B) = \det(A-C)^{N-1}*\det(A+(N-1)C)$$

I fiddled with numerics until I found this formula. I have no proof other than it works for (lotsa) values I tested.

Using this you can get the eigenvalues via the characteristic equation:

$$0 = \det(B - \lambda I_{PN} ) = \det((A-\lambda I_P)-C)^{N-1}*\det((A-\lambda I_P)+(N-1)C)$$

Comment: How can this be true? The characteristic polynomial to the left is of degree $PN$ while the right hand side polynomial is of degree $2P$?

Comment: Intriguing formula, would seriously be interested in a proof!

Comment: This is similar to the {{A,B},{B,A}} example from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

in fact it's a generalization of it. It's not clear why this particular generalization works though.

Comment: Found a proof on MO: 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179377/block-matrix-determinant

Comment: Thanks, your ans correct but in my case A-B not invertible

Comment: Naveen: Read the given proof more carefully, it applies even if A-B is not invertible, this is done by a limiting argument.
@amcalde thanks!